# How to interpret invariant subspaces in the definition of irreducible representation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, definition

I have this sentence in my notes:

> A representation $D$ from a group $G$ to matrices $M(V)$ acting on a
>   vector space $V$ is irreducible if and only if $V$ has no non-trivial
>   invariant proper subspaces.

I have the following questions:

- Why do we write $M(V)$, not just $M$? Does this mean that the matrices $M(V)$ is referring to are made of columns of vectors in vector space $V$? That would be reasonable I believe.
- Does "no non-trivial invariant proper subspaces" mean that given any vector $v \in V $ and and matrix $M \in D$, and if $M$ acts on $v$, than all of its components change? In other words, none of the components of $Mv$ and $v$ are the same. Is this correct?

Comment: $M(V)$ is usually written $\operatorname{End}(V)$, the vector space of linear maps $V \to V$. This is the same as matrices after choosing a basis of $V$. An invariant subspace is a sub-vector-space $U \subseteq V$ such that $Mu \in U$ for any matrix $M$ given by the representation, and any $u \in U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it  a representation of $G$ on $V$ would be a homomorphism,  say $D$, from $G$ to $M(V)$.

The notion of an *invariant subspace* is then, that of a subspace $U\subset V$ with $AU\subset U\,\forall A\in D(G)$.